# Can't create WebPart without privileges Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, active-directory, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012, user-accounts

i got a simple question
I have a server, i access it via remote desktop, when i try to create a new WebPart in visual studio 2012 got this error :

[image]

i tell my IT administrator, to give me the rights privileges, 
He said he can't give me the administrator rights and, he tell me to find another way to create my sharepoint's developments.

And he don't want to create an AD group and create rights privileges.

So my question is : There is another way to create WebParts or other developments without the administrator rights ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop SharePoint solutions in Visual Studio on Windows Vista and Windows 7 systems, UAC requires that you run Visual Studio as a system administrator.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231582(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your VS application as administrator?

Right click on your VS application to find the below options.

[image]

Comment: You might have to develop in your own environment then and just deploy to live?

Comment: I have to develop on the server machine ...I need to prove that , '' I need admin privileges '' to my IT administrator , or maybe there is another way to develop without right...